# Contact Form working in Chrome, not in IE/Firefox

Tags: php, forms, google-chrome, firefox, contact-form

Having some trouble with the contact form on my website, http://www.techcom.co.nz/

It works fine on google chrome, however on IE and Firefox it doesn't send any message and just redirects back up to the top of the page/refreshes the page.

Here is the php code for the form:

```
// EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINE BELOW AS REQUIRED

$send_email_to = "techcomnz@gmail.com";

function send_email($name,$email,$email_subject,$email_message)
{
global $send_email_to;  

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$email. "\r\n";

$message = "<strong>Email = </strong>".$email."<br>";
$message .= "<strong>Name = </strong>".$name."<br>";
$message .= "<strong>Message = </strong>".$email_message."<br>";
@mail($send_email_to, $email_subject, $message,$headers);
return true;
}

function validate($name,$email,$message,$subject)
{
$return_array = array();
$return_array['success'] = '1';
$return_array['name_msg'] = '';
$return_array['email_msg'] = '';
$return_array['message_msg'] = '';
$return_array['subject'] = '';

if($email == '')
{
$return_array['success'] = '0';
$return_array['email_msg'] = 'email is required';
}
else
{
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
  $return_array['success'] = '0';
  $return_array['email_msg'] = 'enter valid email.';  
 }
}

if($name == '')
{
 $return_array['success'] = '0';
 $return_array['name_msg'] = 'name is required';
}
else
{
  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
  $return_array['success'] = '0';
 $return_array['name_msg'] = 'enter valid name.';
}
}


if($subject == '')
{
 $return_array['success'] = '0';
 $return_array['subject_msg'] = 'subject is required';
}

if($message == '')
{
 $return_array['success'] = '0';
 $return_array['message_msg'] = 'message is required';
}
else
{
if (strlen($message) < 2) {
  $return_array['success'] = '0';
  $return_array['message_msg'] = 'enter valid message.';
}
}
return $return_array;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$return_array = validate($name,$email,$message,$subject);
if($return_array['success'] == '1')
{
send_email($name,$email,$subject,$message);
}

header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();

?>
```

and here is the html:

```
    <fieldset id="contact_form">
      <div id="msgs"> </div>
      <form id="cform" name="cform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Full Name*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Full Name*') this.value = ''"
                        onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Full Name*'" />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Email Address*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email Address*') this.value = ''"
                        onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Email Address*'" />
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="Subject*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Subject*') this.value = ''"
                        onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Subject*'" />
        <textarea id="msg" name="message" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your Message*') this.value = ''"
                        onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Your Message*'">Your Message*</textarea>
        <button id="submit" class="button" style=""> Send Message</button>
      </form>
    </fieldset>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Try adding a `type="submit"` to `<button id="submit" class="button" style="">` This is a known issue with older versions of IE that won't submit on click, if that's what your question is about. If so, you can also try using an input type of submit button, instead of just a button.

Comment: To decrease the amount of inline-JavaScript you have, try adding the placeholder attribute instead: `<input type="text" id="foo" placeholder="Foo *" />` This way, if your form fields are blank, then the placeholder text takes over. (Note this does not work in IE < 10)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the action attribute blank will cause most browsers to submit the form data to the current page by reloading it with the data in GET or POST.

If this is your intention, try removing the `action=""` altogether as it has been known to cause issues with older browsers.

Comment: Still no luck, I tried removing the action, and also tried including a submit type for the button as commented above but both to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm wondering whether your inline JavaScript is being parsed by Chrome but there are errors in FF, et al. I haven't had a chance to test it out, but can you open the console in Firefox and check for specific errors? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: Thanks for your reply, since yesterday (and with no change from me) the Contact form has now started working in Firefox, But not in IE. And my pretty photo which was working perfectly now opens up multiple windows in firefox. The javascript errors I get are:--- Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. ---- SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead  ----  Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  --- Any ideas?